# Overloading error messages in Django forms

Tags: django, forms, error-handling, overloading

Hi I'm trying to give some custom error messages to my django forms.  Is there anyplace I can look to find the keys for each default error message to over load?

For instance, here's my email form

```
email = forms.EmailField(
    min_length=6,
    max_length=60,
    error_messages={
        'required':'Please fill in all of the fields',
        'invalid':'Please enter a valid email format',
        'invalid_length':'Email must be inbetween 6 and 60 characters'
    },
```

The error_messages with keys 'required' and 'invalid' overload successfully but I don't know any of the other keys for the other errors (I just guessed for that third one).

The default error message I'm getting for the length is "Ensure this value has at least 6 characters (it has 5)."

If anyone knows the right key that would be great, but it would be nice to know where to find these keys so I can overload other errors as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They depend on the field and the validators that field implements. You can see what you can expect if you search for "default_error_messages" in the `fields.py` in the django source:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py

For example, the `CharField` implements [two extra validators](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L203) [`MaxLengthValidator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L216) and [`MinLengthValidator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L206) so if you want to override the messages for those errors (in the case they are raise), you can add to your `error_messages`:

```
error_messages : {
    'min_length' : '...',
    'max_length' : '...', 
}
```